# Assign column in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I'm trying to migrate a code from PySpark to SparkR. To modify some columns I used ´withColumn´ in PySpark. However, in SparkR it generates a new column. I then tried something like

```
df$a <- f(df$a)
```

That's well and good. However, suppose I want to use that inside a function or for loop and repeat it for a number of variables. In this case, it sadly doesn't work:

```
df[['a']] <- f(df[['a']])
```

I realized it *does* work when doing the following:

```
df$a <- f(df[['a']])
```

I definitely need to assing using either `[[<-` or some other way. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With column should work just fine in Spark 2.0.0+

```
library(magrittr)

df <- createDataFrame(iris)
df %>% withColumn("Sepal_Length", lit(1)) %>% columns
## [1] "Sepal_Length" "Sepal_Width"  "Petal_Length" "Petal_Width"  "Species"
```

but if you work with earlier version you can always use `$<-` as a function:

```
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)

df %>% `$<-`("Sepal_Length", lit(1)) %>% columns
## [1] "Sepal_Length" "Sepal_Width"  "Petal_Length" "Petal_Width"  "Species"

df %>% `$<-`("Sepal_Length", lit(1)) %>% head
##   Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
## 1            1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2            1         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3            1         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4            1         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5            1         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6            1         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

So all you need to make it work with variable is `do.call`:

```
x <- "Sepal_Length"

do.call(`$<-`, list(df, x, lit(1))) %>% columns
```

Comment: Hi, that works as is. However, if you try putting the expression inside a for loop or function, with a changing variable instead of "Sepal_Length", it interprets that variable as a name, not a string. I tried using NSE to solve that, but I'm no expert and it's tricky. I don't mark this as an answer since it doesn't solve the main issue - being able to use the expression inside a function. Thanks anyway.